# MSSQL, как включить подсказки при вводе кода/команд?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Установил Microsoft SQL 2012 Express, Только начинаю изучать.
Собственно, есть там какая-нибудь функция, чтобы при вводе кода, появлялся список вариантов продолжения слова.
Пробовал Ctrl + Space (как в Visual Studio), но это не работает.

После установки в настройках ничего не менял.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите кнопку InellySense на внрхней панели, справа от кнопки execute. На скрине видно что она зажата. Или в основных настройка, вкладка T-sql-IntellySense

Comment: Посмотрел, там всё включено.
Что дальше? :\

Comment: @ЕгорСпириади из коробки это все возможности, все остальное это тулы и патчи не от говернора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я пользуюсь dbForge SQL Complete.
Как по мне, очень удобное расширение.

Comment: Чуть не жмакнул "не является ответом" ))) Пользуюсь тем же расширением, весьма рекомендую. Но всё же не мешало бы расписать немного подробнее ответ.